# I see no [item] here

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/item)'s excerpt:

> A separate and particular thing, heading, entry or object.

That's about as generic as it gets.  In practice [item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/item) has three uses:

- an item in a compound UI element, such as [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview) or [combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/combobox).  [item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/item) doesn't add any meaning.
- an item in a data structure, such as [list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/list) or [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays).  [item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/item) doesn't add any meaning here, either.
- some domain-specific thing being frobbed in the asker's problem.  In this role [item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/item) means too many different things to be useful for searching or categorization.  It's possible  some clusters in these uses might become apparent after removing the first two uses, justifying new tags for the domain-specific things, but [item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/item) itself won't become useful.

None of the top [item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/item) answerers has more than 2 answers or 27 score, so it isn't useful for experts.  ([listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview) on its own has a user with 739 score from 266 answers.)  [item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/item) does have 4 followers for some reason.

[item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/item) is one of those tags that result from people typing all the nouns in their question title into the tag box.  It's just not useful for anything.

---

<sup>I'm still subject to suggested-edits review, so it's not clear how much I can help with burnination/retagging.  My apologies if making a burnination-request is out of order until I reach 2k.</sup>

Comment: Toast it. I haven't found questions in need of retagging on first look, did you? If not, they maybe just request deletion of the tag.

Comment: Don't forget we have [entity], [element] and [object] as a replacement. Go ahead and delete it :-)

Comment: You can certainly make burninate requests, however I would advise you not to do the burnination yourself. It will only clog the queue. If the amount of tagged questions is low enough, a high-rep user can sweep them, otherwise a mod/dev should assist and automate it.

Answer (score 16):

I looked through the first 200 questions and [item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/item) doesn't add any value to the description. Most of the question have other meaningful tags. A few lack that, but removing [item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/item) won't make any difference.

Burninate it.

### Update

I've updated the tag wiki to state that it should not be used, linking to this post.