# Get rid of all the [items]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag, that is.

[The "item" tag was deleted in July](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262731/i-see-no-item-here). All of the same reasoning applies to the [items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/items) tag: the word is just way too general. It's often associated with collections of objects, but it doesn't mean anything on its own.

I've already started untagging some of these; anyone want to help?

Comment: it really need to be blacklisted

Comment: @BryanChen I could totally get behind that. Just didn't want to get too demanding!

Comment: @BryanChen blacklisting seems awfully extreme. It's not like the tag keeps getting recreated.  Burninate it and see if someone tries to recreate it again.  Then it is time to discuss blacklisting

Comment: Blacklisting is reserved only for the most egregiously bad tags.  It's expensive, and only available to the SE developers.  This tag isn't bad enough; it has to be a really bad tag to qualify for the blacklist.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with removing this. The tag has little apparent meaning. "Items" is definitely *not* a programming topic, and I'm not even sure what topic it's supposed to refer to. It is *highly* vague and ambiguous, not even really on-topic, adds nothing to the post, and does not mean the same thing in all common contexts.